# change port for wso2 api manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I started using wso2 api manager for providing gateway to our project rest api services.

I am successfully running the api interface locally on this url

```
https://localhost:9443/publisher
```

Now, we had to install the wso2 api manager on linux machine.

Only blocker is 9943 port is not open by server team.

They had provided 10397,8280,8243,7711 as available ports.

But even trying with  [reference](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Changing+the+Default+Ports+with+Offset), port is not changed on wso2server startup.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What is the port offset value you have provided. If your offset is 3, the current port value is offsetting by 3 and publisher page should be able to access from 9446

Comment: I am adding the offset as 454. But server is starting with https://localhost:9897/store. I had also change port in api-manager.xml as mentioned in above link. But its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able change port to 8280 by specify negative value in carbon.xml

```
 <Offset>-1163</Offset>
```

My Observation is that increment of ports from 9443 to larger value is not working due to conflict with other ports used by embedded products while decrements to lesser value is working fine.

I hope it helps to other users.

Comment: Be aware that API Manager uses 8280 by default, so it might lead to a conflict of ports if the offset doesn't change this port as well. Give a look here: https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon410/Default+Ports+of+WSO2+Products