# Disable Port 9443 from API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I don't want to expose ports to users.
therefore I want to use "https://hostname/devportal", "https://hostname/publisher" rather than "https://hostname:9443/devportal", "https://hostname:9443/publisher". what should I do?

Please help me on this.

thanks.  (API manager version: 4.0)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [change port for wso2 api manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43677211/change-port-for-wso2-api-manager)    "hostname/devportal" is equal to "hostname:80/devportal" (or 443 for https).

Comment: for such configuration changes, you can edit the `deployment.toml` file and redirect your traffic to your desired URL you can put your instance behind a reverse proxy like Nginx. You can find all the information you want in the official documents

Comment: @Jeppe  yes  "https/hostname/devportal"

Comment: @pouyan021  Could you share the link?  i can not find it. help me on this.

Comment: You can refer [Configuring Proxy Server](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.0.0/install-and-setup/setup/setting-up-proxy-server-and-the-load-balancer/configuring-the-proxy-server-and-the-load-balancer/#configuring-the-proxy-server-and-the-load-balancer)

Comment: @HisanHunais Thanks for answering... now, i did not use Nginx... so i just added [transport.https.properties]
proxyPort = 443     ... but still not works...am i wrong?

Comment: There is no APIM specific configuration to enable it. You can use any proxy server to route the traffic from default https port to 9443.

Comment: @VithursaMahendrarajah  Thanks..You mean such as NGNIX, right?  let me try~~

Comment: Yes. You can use NGINX

Comment: @VithursaMahendrarajah  resolved...all many Thanks.~

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following two properties to the `deployment.toml` if you want to start WSO2 server on port 443. (Tip: Start everything on a fresh pack, if you are trying following on a pack you already started you may have to change already registered callback URLs)

```
[transport.https.properties] 
proxyPort = 443
port = 443
```

Also, for an application to bind to a port <1000(In this case 443) it needs root permissions. Hence you will have to start the server with a user who has root access.

Having said that, this is not a good deployment pattern as to expose your servers directly to external access. You should probably deploy an LB fronting the WSO2 servers and expose LB to the external users.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. I'm going to use this on an internal system. So we will use port 9443 as it is. However, we do not want to disclose the port to internal users. To do that, can I use a proxy server like NGNIX as suggested by someone else above?

Comment: Yes, you can. Refer to this document for that. https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/setting-up-proxy-server-and-the-load-balancer/configuring-the-proxy-server-and-the-load-balancer/